# Invalid entry to fstab and now does not boot

Tags: boot

I added an entry to auto mount disk on startup by editing fstab. It looks like something went wrong with the entry and now I cannot boot it up

Is there any way to access the OS?

Comment: Yes. Try booting up with a live USB, go with the try mode and clear the mess from `fstab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Live USB and use that to edit your fstab file. below is example of mine. but read carefully.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=<your-UUID-FOR-/-PARTITION> /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=<your-UUID-FOR-/BOOT/EFI-PARTITION(IF YOU USE UEFI)>  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=<your-UUID-FOR-SWAP-PARTITION> none            swap    sw              0       0
```

use command:

```
blkid
```

to get your disk UUID. 
after finish editing your fstab, reboot.

Thank you.